# Convert variables and strings to datetime format

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have the following variables and formatted data:

- Scheduling_StartDate_Month = 10
- Scheduling_StartDate_Day = 1
- Scheduling_StartDate_Year = 2012
- Scheduling_StartTime = 3:00 PM

I need to combine them into one variable 'schedstart' of type 'datetime' to insert into my database, and I'm completely lost. I have tried to research the issues, and found suggestions to use mktime() or sttodate() but I couldn't find any reliable syntax guidelines.

How do I combine those variables using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider concatenating in a proper format on the PHP:

```
<?php

$dateString = $Scheduling_StartDate_Month."/".$Scheduling_StartDate_Day."/".$Scheduling_StartDate_Year." ".$Scheduling_StartTime;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('".$dateString."', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')");

?>
```

Comment: is there any way to do this just in php?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following which use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) functions:

```
select 
  str_to_date(
    concat(Scheduling_StartDate_Year,'-',
          Scheduling_StartDate_Month, '-',
          Scheduling_StartDate_Day, ' ',
          Scheduling_StartTime), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') as yourDate
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d80df/5)

Results:

```
yourDate
2012-10-01 03:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why on earth you'd want to do this in SQL when it's super easy to do in PHP.

(It's usually best to put as little strain as possible on the SQL server as that's usually the bottle-neck, plus, it's much uglier to piece together using `CONCAT` in SQL)

MySQL dates are essentially just strings formatted in a particular way. e.g. `2008-12-31 23:59:59`

So just take your different date pieces and stuff them together so they look like that, and then use it in your SQL query as you please (put it in single quotes).

see [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more details.

Easiest way might look like this:

```
$mysql_formatted_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Scheduling_StartDate_Year-$Scheduling_StartDate_Month-$Scheduling_StartDate_Day $Scheduling_StartTime"));
```

i.e., let `strtotime` parse out your date and handle converting am/pm to 24-hour time, then use `date` to force it into the correct format.

```
mysql_query("SELECT '$mysql_formatted_date' ...");
```